# Function for changes a cell in a list

Tags: java, kotlin, arraylist

I have a list of `User` objects with the values `​​name` and `date`, which at position `0` have the values ​​`Kate` and `15:37`. What a function should look like, which, when called, will change the values ​​in this cell (at position 0) to `Peter` and `15:15` Here is my code:

```
class Test {
 private var list = mutableListOf<User>()
 private var user: User? = null

 private fun addItem() {
       user = User("Kate","15:37")
       list.add(0, user!!)
}
}
```

at a certain place in the code, I call the `addItem` method and I  have a cell with the values `Kate` and `15:37`. After that, I want to call a function that will change the values ​​in this cell ...

Comment: As this is Kotlin code could we do something like: `list.map { it.name = "value"; it.date = "value"}

Comment: thank you. but in this case I get the same result : when this function is called, a new element is added to the list and that all. I need a function that I called - and the value in the cell has changed. for example, I have a list of `User` objects with the values ​​`name` and `date`, which at position `0` have the values ​​`Kate` and `15:37`. I called the function - and the values ​​in this cell at position `0` changed to `Sam` and `15:15`. Something like this)

Comment: your question is not clear enough, what are the conditions to change a cell? or which cell should be changed? btw you dont need the iterator

Comment: Yes, I already got it, that I don't need iterator. It is doesn't matter what is conditions for changed cells. I call function - and the values of the cell in he position 0 should be changed.

Comment: Kotlin has an emphasis on functional programming and immutable.  What you are trying in the code above is a mutable imperative approach.  One of the foundations of functional programming is that a function doesnt change/mutate its input (parameters).  That being said if you can not change your method call, you are likely going to have to change `list` to be a `MutableList`.  if you could make `updateCell` return a `List` you should be able to use the code provided in my first comment above.

Comment: then you can do something like this `list.first = "something"` and your list should be mutable unless you can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to change the item at position 0 in the list?

```
list[0] = User("Peter", "15:15")
```

If you want to replace the item with one that's a copy, but with certain changes:

```
list[0] = list[0].copy(name="Peter")
```

If you want to keep the same object at position 0, but change its state:

```
// note the use of var, so the properties are mutable
data class User(var name: String, var date: String)

// "get item 0, if it's not null, set these things on it",
// this is just a neat and concise way to do it
list[0]?.run {
    name = "Peter"
    date = "15:15"
}
```

Comment: I want that I could change data in the item in the real time

Comment: @Monica I added some other options, including making the item mutable so you can just change its state. If that's what you mean?